# How to Add Target OS in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0

I want to add linux as one of the target OS, how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Target OS sets `TargetFramework` property of the .csproj. There are no target frameworks specific for linux cause it seems there are no system specific API implemented/exposed by .NET at the moment, so `None` (`net6.0` for `TargetFramework` property) is an option to go. From [.NET 5+ OS-specific TFMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms) part of the docs:

> The `net5.0` and `net6.0` TFMs include technologies that work across different platforms. Specifying an OS-specific TFM makes APIs that are specific to an operating system available to your app, for example, Windows Forms or iOS bindings. OS-specific TFMs also inherit every API available to their base TFM, for example, the net5.0 TFM.
>
> .NET 5 introduced the `net5.0-windows` OS-specific TFM, which includes Windows-specific bindings for WinForms, WPF, and UWP APIs. .NET 6 introduces further OS-specific TFMs.

What you can specify is Runtime Identifier (RID):

> RID values are used to identify target platforms where the application runs.
> They're used by .NET packages to represent platform-specific assets in NuGet packages. The following values are examples of RIDs: `linux-x64`, `ubuntu.14.04-x64`, `win7-x64`, or `osx.10.12-x64`.
> For the packages with native dependencies, the RID designates on which platforms the package can be restored.

Currently available Linux RIDs are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#linux-rids) and full list is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/src/runtime.json).